# Rails: CSS changes in developement not visible

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Rails 5.0

Since I've done this command-line : ENV=production rake assets:precompile

when i change CSS I can see them in local instantly.

I have to kill the server, do this command-line again (ENV=production rake assets:precompile) in order to see the change I made.

Thaks for your help.

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails requires you to pre-compile assets (css,js,etc) in production after you change anything in assets. However in development assets are compiled live by default.

If you want to compile assets live in production (Not Recommended):

then change `config.assets.compile=false` in `config/environments/production.rb` to:

`config.assets.compile = true`

That is Rails should recompile the assets when it detects that a new version of the source assets is there.

On production, you usually want to set it to false and handle asset compilation during deployment. For this, you have to run

RAILS_ENV=production bin/rails assets:precompile

Usually, if you deploy using Capistrano, it takes care of that.

Note: In rails 4 or earlier it was `RAILS_ENV=production bin/rake assets:precompile` but in Rails 5.x `rake` is merged into `rails` so you must use `RAILS_ENV=production bin/rails assets:precompile`.

Comment: Thanks for your help.
In development, if I change the CSS I can see the change I made on localhost.
Before I made this command line : ENV=production rake assets:precompile
it was working well.

Comment: So what you want to say is after you ran the command `ENV=production rake assets:precompile` , you cannot see the change in CSS in development?

Comment: Yes.

Usually when I change my CSS, I am going to http://localhost:3000/ I wait few seconds and I can see the changes I made. 

Since yesterday, it's not working. I didn't touch anything in the config/environements files but I ran this command-line ENV=production rake assets:precompile.

Comment: Make sure you haven't set the environment to production in your initializers. If you type `rails s` it runs in development env, if not set in initializers.
Or Try `RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rails s` If all works well after running server in development, that means your server was running in production.

Comment: The environment is set to development but it's still not working. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Try running `rails assets:precompile --trace` If there is some error in compiling the assets, it will be displayed. Else your browser might have cached the CSS due to which changes are not shown on fly.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

In config/environments/development.rb,
I had config.assets.debug set to false instead of true.